# Align CSS "close button" in announcement bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm working on an announcement bar for my website, but I got stuck on positioning the "close" button.

The bar itself works just fine, but **I couldn't get to position the "close" button at the right of the announcement bar**, where you usually find them. I've tried using `margin-right`, `padding` and similar solutions but they didn't work.

Also, **I wanted to find the best way to make the button disappear (along with the bar) once it's clicked**

EDIT: Here's the solution, provided by [GrafiCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5334486/graficode).

Here's the code and [you can see it running here](https://jsfiddle.net/ncpthbdy/):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dabar" class="hideonload"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* top-bar */
#dabar {
  background: #1b1c1e;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#dabar a {
  color: #b5e48c;
  border-bottom: 1px;
}

.btn-close {
  margin-left: calc(100vw - 48px);
  margin-top: -16px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 150ms;
}

.btn-close .icon-cross {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.btn-close .icon-cross:before,
.btn-close .icon-cross:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 6.5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.btn-close .icon-cross:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btn-close .icon-cross:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.btn-close .icon-cross span {
  display: block;
}

.btn-close:hover,
.btn-close:focus {
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  background: #05c;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
window.onload = function() //executes when the page finishes loading
{
  setTimeout(func1, 2500);
};

function func1() {
  var el = document.getElementById('dabar');
  el.innerHTML = '<a href="https://imthemoisturizer.com/hola">Empieza aquí</a> | <a href="https://imthemoisturizer.com/en/hi">Start here</a><button class="btn-close" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\'" ><span class="icon-cross"></span></button>';
  el.className = 'showtopbar';
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: `.btn-close { margin-left: calc(100vw - 48px); }`

Comment: Thank you so much! What I don't get is why the button doesn't disappear after being clicked, though. Do you know why that could be happening?

Comment: try `onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\'"`

Comment: Do you mean like this (https://jsfiddle.net/jvfLa7cb/)? I have such a hard time with JS and find it extra difficult, I really appreciate that you're helping me out!

Comment: yes. By the way, why did you also include the button's markup in html? you're creating it dynamically, maybe your markup should be this: https://jsfiddle.net/j0u4wxdL/

Comment: That's exactly what I aimed to do! Thanks a lot! And what do you think is the best way to keep the "close" button centered within the bar itself, along with the text?

Comment: to center the button, edit the above css to `margin-left: calc(50vw - 24px);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll mark the question as resolved and edit the original post with your solution, have a great day!